# What exactly is the topological space $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$?

Tags: general-topology

I have come across the topological space $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$, but I would like to know exactly what it is.

1. Is it a space of all real-valued functions of a real variable?
2. Is it a product space of $\mathbb{R}$ raised to a power of $\mathbb{R}$?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think the definition may depend upon the source you are using.

Comment: Remember that $A^B$ is often notation for the set of functions from $B$ to $A$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is both.  A function $f: A \to B$ assigns a member of $B$ to each member of $A$.  It can be thought of as a "tuple" $v \in B^A$ indexed by the members of $A$, where each element of the tuple is a member of $B$, i.e. $v_a = f(a)$.

Comment: Thank you so much for making things clearer, now I understand it.